# Java issue with Rsentiment package

Tags: java, r, sentiment-analysis

I'm working on sentiment analysis. I'm trying to use Rsentiment package in order to get the score for each sentence of my dataset. When I run the command I get a warning message related to an issue with Java. Does anyone of you have any suggestion? I run it on a Macbook. This is the message that I got:

```
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "(null)".
No Java runtime present, try --request to install.
Errore: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found
Inoltre: Warning message:
running command '/usr/libexec/java_home' had status 1
```

Comment: Do you have Java installed?

Comment: yes! I downloaded the latest version of java

Comment: If you mean Java 9 by latest version then afaik rJava would not work with it yet

Comment: what do you suggest me?? is it necessary to install a previous version of Java??

Comment: Java 8 works for me

Comment: I'm going to install Java 8 and I will try again. Do I need to run something in R in order to fix the problem?

Comment: I tried to install Java 8 but it did not solve the problem. I got the same warning message again.